# Letting users edit ActionMailer emails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer

In my app I would like my admin users to be able to edit the emails that are sent out by my Rails app via ActionMailer.

What would be the best way to do that?

Ideally there would be a rich text editor with HTML and ruby source code formatting. I don't need to have new emails, just editing the existing templates would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a model in which you can store those email templates and then give access to admin to edit those email templates. For rich text editor you can check out `tinymce-rails` `ckeditor` `mercury-rails` `redactor-rails` `rich` gems.

Comment: How do I get ActionMailer to use those models instead of the html templates? Or would it be better to include the Model's rich text fields inside the template for the Mailer?

Comment: Your second option. You can include the Model's text field inside your template for mailer.

Comment: How would I go about letting my using ERB snippets in the model's text fields?
a) how do I parse the ERB into HTML
b) Is there a syntax-aware GUI editor that does ERB syntax highlighting?